# UIKit 2 (getuikit) - Lightbox - Previous / Next on Touch-Enabled Decives

Tags: getuikit

I am using UIKit (getuikit.com version 2, cannot use the version 3 RC at the moment) to display a Lightbox. All works fine except that on iPhone/iPad (I assume it might be all touch-enabled devices), the previous/next arrows don't show, which makes it rather difficult to navigate. How does one enable these arrows either permanently or when I touch the Lightbox somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Arrows are hidden as on touch devices swipe action is available by default allowing your users to change images by swiping do left or right as they normally do in any other gallery app.

If you still want to show arrows to them, you need to override the class `.uk-hidden-touch`

```
.uk-notouch .uk-hidden-notouch,
.uk-touch .uk-hidden-touch {
    display:block!important;
}
```